# How to reload external configuration data in NiFi processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a custom nifi processor that uses external data for some user controlled configuration. I want to know how to signal the processor to reload the data when it is changed.
I was thinking that a flofile could be sent to signal the processor but I am concerned that in a clustered environment only one processor would get the notification and all the others would still be running on old configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The most common ways to watch a file for changes are the JDK WatchService or Apache Commons IO Monitor...

https://www.baeldung.com/java-watchservice-vs-apache-commons-io-monitor-library
https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice

Your processor could use one of these and reload the data when the file changed, just make sure to synchronize access to relevant fields in your processor between the code that is reloading them and the code that is using them during execution.